# How to implement insert function, with no pointer node as a parameter, in binary tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

`tree.h` file that implements all the methods. The insert function is in this file. Everything I try requires a the use of a tree pointer node to be passed as a parameter but we cant change the method headers at all for this assignment so Im lost as to how to implement it. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!!

```
#include "treeNode.h"
#include <iomanip>

template <class V>
class tree {
    TreeNode<V> * root;
    int size;

    public:
    // default constructor                                                      
    // by default, the tree is empty                                            
    tree(){
        root = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }

    // search value x in tree rooted at node t                                  
    bool treeSearch(V x, TreeNode<V>* t){
        if(t == nullptr) return false;
        if(t->getDatum() == x) return true;
        return treeSearch(x, t->getLeft()) || treeSearch(x, t->getRight());
    }

    bool treeSearch(V x){
        treeSearch(x, root);
    }


    // binary search value x in tree rooted at node t                           
    bool treeBSearch(V x, TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return false;
      if(t->getDatum() == x) return true;
      if(t->getDatum() > x)
        return treeBSearch(x, t->getLeft());
      else
        return treeBSearch(x, t->getRight());
    }

    bool treeBSearch(V x){
        return treeBSearch(x, root);
    }

    // check node t is leaf                                                     
    bool isLeaf(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t != nullptr && t->getLeft() == nullptr && t->getRight() == nullptr){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
// find the height of the tree rooted at node t                             
    int height(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return -1;
      if(isLeaf(t)) return 0;
      return 1 + std :: max(height(t->getLeft()), height(t->getRight()));
    }

    int height(){
        return height(root);
    }

    // find the number of nodes of tree rooted at t                             
    int nNodes(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return 0;
      return 1 + nNodes(t->getLeft()) + nNodes(t->getRight());
    }

    int nNodes(){
        return nNodes(root);
    }


    // insert value x to the current tree object                                
    void insert(V x){

    }
// print out the values of tree rooted at x                                 
    // it shows the hierarchy of the tree                                       
    // it will be useful for debugging                                          
    void print(TreeNode<V> * x, int indent){
        if(x == nullptr) return;
        if (x->getRight() != nullptr) {
            print(x->getRight(), indent+4);
        }

        if (indent != 0) {
            cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
        }

        if(x->getRight() != nullptr){
            cout << " /\n" << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
        }

        cout << x->getDatum() << endl;

        if (x->getLeft() != nullptr) {
            cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ' <<" \\\n";
            print(x->getLeft(), indent+4);
        }

    }

    void print(){
        int count = 0;
        print(root, count);
    }

};
```

`treeNode.h` file that has declares methods
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
template <class T>
class TreeNode{
    T datum;
    TreeNode<T>* left, * right;

    public:
    // constructor with datum value, left and right are nullptr                 
    TreeNode(T x){
        datum=x;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    // constructor with datum value, left and right values                      
    TreeNode(T x, TreeNode<T>* lft, TreeNode<T>* rgt){
        datum = x;
        left = lft;
        right = rgt;
    }

    //destructor releases left and right nodes, if not nullptr                  
    ~TreeNode(){
        if (left) {
            delete left;
        }
        if (right) {
            delete right;
        }
    }

    // get datum value                                                          
    T getDatum(){
        return datum;
    }

    // get left pointer                                                         
    TreeNode<T>* getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    // get right pointer                                                        
    TreeNode<T>* getRight(){
        return right;
    }

    // set the left pointer                                                     
    void setLeft(TreeNode<T>* p){
        left = p;
    }
  // set the right pointer                                                    
    void setRight(TreeNode<T>* p){
        right = p;
    }

};
```

`test.cpp` file that tests whether or not the methods work

```
#include "tree.h"

int main(){

    tree<int> myTree;
    myTree.insert(5);
    myTree.insert(3);
    myTree.insert(2);
    myTree.insert(4);
    myTree.insert(8);
    myTree.insert(6);
    myTree.insert(7);
    myTree.insert(9);

    cout << myTree.treeBSearch(9) << endl;
    cout << myTree.treeBSearch(11) << endl;
    cout << myTree.nNodes() << endl;

    cout << "The Tree Looks Like: " << endl;
    myTree.print();

    tree<int> myTree2;
    myTree2.insert(4);
    myTree2.insert(2);
    myTree2.insert(1);
    myTree2.insert(3);

    myTree2.insert(7);
    myTree2.insert(5);


   // myTree2.print();                                                          
}
```

Comment: Can you try and explain your problem more succinctly? I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: You need to construct a node inside `insert` that holds the value passed to insert and then add that node into the list.  Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @NathanOliver it would be done as such correct? TreeNode<V> *t = new TreeNode<V>; because every time I try to do that I recieve an error.

Comment: Maybe you should ask how to get that code working and include the error you are getting.

Comment: @NathanOliver I get the error:  no matching constructor for initialization